# Show statements for error residual and Taylors Law

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, regression

I have some data from a lake. "Counts" is the response variable and is a number for the organism in the lake. I also have a variable "stations" that indicate every parts of the lake (there are 45 stations).

It can be assumed that:
$$Y_i=\mu_i+\epsilon_i$$
with $E\epsilon_i=0$, $V \epsilon_i=\psi V(\mu_i)$

and $\mu_i=\beta_{stations}$
being a station specific station mean value. It will makes to use normal distribution as response distribution.

Then I be introduced to a new law the Taylor Law: It states that there is a power law relationship between mean and variance when counting organism. And specifically the variance function is given by:
$$V(\mu)=\mu^b$$
for some power $b≥0$. And $\xi_i=E\epsilon_i^2$

Then I have to show that if the Taylors law holds then
$$log(\xi_i)=log(\psi)+blog(\mu_i)$$

And I have to show that if $\epsilon_i$ is normally distributed then $V \epsilon_i^2=2  \xi_i^2$.

I understand it most, intuitively. The $\epsilon$ is the residual error and $\mu$ is the mean and then there is a relationship between the mean and variance for some unknown $b≥0$. But I'm a bit confused what $\xi$ and $\psi$ is and and how I should gather the information to show these two statements.
I hope anyone can help me?

Comment: $\log(\xi_i)=\log(\psi)+b\log(\mu_i)$ is equivalent to $\xi_i=\psi \mu_i^b$ which in this case may be  $\text{Var}(\epsilon_i) = \psi\text{Var}(\mu_i) $

Comment: Thank you!! That makes sense when I combine it with the formula V(X)=E^2(X)-(E(X))^2

Comment: @henry Can you help me with the other one? What variance formula holds only for normal distribution?

Comment: If $\epsilon_i \sim N(0,\xi_i)$ then it is true  $\text{Var}(\epsilon_i^2) = 2\xi_i^2$, since $E[\epsilon_i^2]=\xi_i$ and   $E[\epsilon_i^4]=3\xi_i^2$

Comment: Aah makes sense. But how did you found $E(\epsilon_i^4)$?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Moments